# Is R and Hadoop related?

Tags: r, hadoop, comparison, analysis, large-data

Is R and Hadoop related? As I understand both are used for large scale data analysis, and calculations. Also I noticed Google and Facebook use R, Mapreduce framework is from Google and they use it for search.

Is R and Hadoop even comparable? If not for what purpose each one is used?

Comment: http://ml.stat.purdue.edu/rhipe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [here](http://www.quora.com/How-can-R-and-Hadoop-be-used-together) suggests that you can use hadoop to store you data and write map reduce jobs that can then provide output that can be analyzed through R.